# Declaration of 2D array dimension - first dimension must be the one element from 1D array

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Array_first_dimension

Implicit none

Integer::i
Integer,parameter::Br_sn_cv=11,Br_sn_gr=Br_sn_cv-1,Br_nn_mre=10
Integer,parameter,dimension(Br_nn_mre)::Br_nn_cv=[15,12,17,13,16,11,25,45,21,35],Br_nn_gra=Br_nn_cv-1
Integer,dimension(Br_sn_gr)::SN_Tip
Integer,dimension(Br_nn_gra,Br_nn_mre)::NN_Tip


End Program Array_first_dimension
```

My intention is to declare the first dimension of `NN_tip` array in way that first dimension is always element from Br_nn_gra wich is corresponding to actual value of Br_nn_mre `(NN_Tip(15,1),NN_Tip(12,1)...NN_Tip(35,10))`.

I got the message at the end of compilation:

```
Error: Expression  must be scalar
Error: The module or main program array 'nn_tip'  must have constant shape
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This is what I want to do:
`NN_Tip(15,1),NN_Tip(12,1)...NN_Tip(35,10),
`

Comment: you can not create such a "ragged" array in fortran.

Comment: What is closer solution?